# Parsing specific line from xml with same name

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml with 10 records and the structure is:

```
<entry>
<title>My Title</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://myweb.com/posts/one.html"/>
<published>2014-07-07T00:34:00+00:00</published>
<updated>2014-07-07T00:34:00+00:00</updated>
<id>http://myweb.com/posts/one.html</id>
<author>
<name>Myweb.com</name>
</author>
<content>
Some Content Here
</content>
<link rel="enclosure" href="http://myweb.com/uploads/300px-300px.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length=""/>
</entry>
```

I am using the code bellow to parse it and its almost working great except that i can't fetch the image url that is in the duplicate line:

```
 <link rel="enclosure" href="http://myweb.com/uploads/300px-300px.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length=""/>
```

My code is:

```
$url = "http://myweb.com/posts.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->entry as $PRODUCT) {

$my_title = trim($PRODUCT->title);
$url = trim($PRODUCT->id);
$im = (string)$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]');

echo $my_title . " " . $url . " " . $im;
echo "<br>";

}
```

This: `$im = (string)$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]');`
Returns "Array" and not the url inisde href.

Thanks

Comment: Solved...
Used $im = (string)$PRODUCT->link[1]['href'];

Comment: `(string)$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]')[0]->href` or `(string)$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href')[0]` would work, too. It's just an array that get's returned from `->xpath()`, access it as usual.

Comment: @hakre You mean `['href']`, not `->href`. Also, I suspect @ThW is right that a namespace prefix needs registering; SimpleXML accessors special-case the default namespace as though it's the same as no namespace at all, but the XPath engine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This: `$im = (string)$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]');` Returns "Array" and not the url inisde href.

Whenever you see a string containing the word "Array" in PHP, where you were expecting something else, you need to think "hm, I seem to have cast an array to a string, how did that happen?" (Similarly, if you unexpectedly see the string "A", consider the possibility that it's a one-letter substring of "Array").

In this case, the reason why is quite simple: if you look up [the manual page for the `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), you'll see that it returns an array unless there is an error (not finding a match is not an error, and will give you an empty array).

The only reason this is surprising, is that most [methods on that class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) return another instance of the same class, with magic overloads for things like the `(string)` cast. However, all of those objects represent a more-or-less coherent fragment of the XML document (e.g. 1 or more consecutive nodes, or siblings filtered by a particular tag-name), and can never represent "nothing". An XPath result could be empty, or contain nodes of various types from all over the document; I don't know for sure, but I suspect this is why an array return was chosen here rather than another variety of `SimpleXMLElement` object.

So `$PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]')[0]` will give you the first result (or `$xpath_results = $PRODUCT->xPath('//link[@rel="enclosure"]'); $im = $xpath_results[0]` if you can't rely on at least PHP 5.4, or want to insert a check in between for no nodes being matched).

There are a few extra catches here, though:

- Namespaces: [as ThW points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629207/157957), Atom feeds often have an XML namespace declaration, and you need to handle this in your XPath query by registering a prefix, e.g. `$product->registerXpathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');` and then use it in your XPath expression (e.g. `//atom:link` rather than `//link`).
- You didn't specify that you wanted the `href` attribute: either change your XPath expression to select it (`//link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href`) or change your access to grab it from the `SimpleXMLElement` returned (`$xpath_results[0]['href']`).

Stick it all together (and get rid of that ugly and unusual all-caps variable name), and the compact version (no error checking, minimum readability) would be either:

```
$product->registerXpathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
(string)$product->xPath('//atom:link[@rel="enclosure"]')[0]['href']
```

or

```
$product->registerXpathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
(string)$product->xPath('//atom:link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it is part of an Atom feed. This means it has a namespace. To use Xpath on an XML with namespaces, you have to register an alias/prefix the namespace. This is a little complex with SimpleXML, you have to do it on each element, you're calling the xpath() method and it will always return an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($feed->entry as $product) {
  $product->registerXpathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  var_dump((string)$product->xpath('//atom:link[@rel="enclosure"]')[0]['href']);
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/170439

With DOMXpath this is more easier, the namespaces only need to be registered on the DOMXpath object once and DOMXpath::evaluate() can return scalar values. The second argument is the context for the Xpath expression:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

foreach($xpath->evaluate('//atom:entry') as $product) {
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href)', $product));
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/170444